# Domain error during implicit conversion of VARBINARY value to a NUMERIC field?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, sybase

**I m getting this error while update one of the table. Any idea in which case this error might occur?**
I use sybase 12, java 7 with hibernate.
My column type in sybase is `Numeric(19,0)` and data type in java code is `BigInteger`

```
    com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: 
Domain error during implicit conversion of VARBINARY value '¬?' to a NUMERIC field.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that most lightly that you have specified you **BigDecimal** with no digits to the right of the decimal place.

Your SQL specifies **Numeric(19,0)** = which is a precesision of 19 with a scale of 0 ... ie no digits to the right of the DP(decimal place)